# Do objects that implement IDisposable and/or have a Finalizer live until Generation 2 is collected?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I was fairly sure that I had read (in Richter's C# book) that objects that implement IDisposable and/or which have a Finalizer live until Generation 2.  However, I can't find the reference, and my test application doesn't seem to support my belief.

Can anyone else confirm/deny?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They certainly survive to Gen 1 since they are placed on a queue for the finalizer to get round to them.  However if the finalizer gets to them before a Gen 1 collection they won't survive to Gen 2.

I haven't got that book for comparison but are you sure your not confusing this with items on the large object heap?  The large object heap is only collected on a Gen 2 collection.

Comment: Thanks, that supports what I'd seen in my testing.  It is entirely possible that I'd confused this with the LOH - I obviously haven't been interviewing enough, as I'm starting to forget stuff like this :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Anthony says, finalization delays garbage collection (i.e. the object will typically be promoted while it waits for the finalizer to run).

Implementing `IDisposable` on its own has no effect on garbage collection - the GC doesn't "know" about `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

Something I wanted to add: a properly implemented IDisposable pattern should call

```
GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
```

That way, the garbage collector won't have to wait until the object is finalized. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx).